# How to manipulate #REF! value

Tags: excel, vb.net

I need to gather data from Excel and populate my GridView as homework. I got stuck on a column that has a value `#REF!` and it returns a negative value instead, -237823429.

I have tried to replace the value.ToString with this loop

```
Dim SpecialChars As String = "~!@#$%^&*()|?{}[]<>"
Dim tempString As String = xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 22).Value.ToString
For c As Integer = 0 To SpecialChars.Length - 1
    tempString.Replace(SpecialChars.Chars(c), "")
Next
```

Still no clue what to do

Comment: You do know that the #REF! means that the formula on which that reference is based is flawed or no longer working.  Correct the formula you correct the #REF! error.  The question becomes how do you want to handle BAD data in your source input?  Think of it this way: I expect a file to be in format X.  I get it in format X.1 which is a new version.  Do I continue to process or do I let the user know I don't want to proceed due to variances in expectations.

Comment: Or check if it's equals to `#ref!` don't copy it in the first place instead of replacing those characters with an empty string?

Comment: thank you for such quick reply, I want to handle the bad data. And when I check if its equals to #REF! it already has a value